# Script a SP2010 Management Shell function call

Tags: powershell

I have a small script that refreshes a users profile. Occasionally I need to run the script on a large number of users which takes some time because I need to type each one individually.

```
PS C:\> . .\Scripts\CustomScript.ps1
PS C:\> FunctionCall "user1"
PS C:\> FunctionCall "user2"
```

Also not as important but sometimes a function will fail if and report an error. Can that text be captured?

Comment: I was able to solve this by including the function calls within the .ps1 file and I was able to capture the errors using a try catch block around the failing line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing the following:

instead of this

```
PS C:\> . .\Scripts\CustomScript.ps1
PS C:\> FunctionCall "user1"
PS C:\> FunctionCall "user2"
```

I opened the ps1 file and added the function calls to the file as so

```
Function FunctionCall ([string]$username) {
    try{
        //Do Something
    } catch {
        //Write error to log file
    }
}
Write-Host "Starting Script..."
FunctionCall "user1"
FunctionCall "user2"
Write-Host "Finished"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
Start-SPAssignment -Global
Start-Transcript
$web = Get-SPWeb ...
$web.Users | % {
  FunctionCall $_
}
End-Transcript
Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```